# The problem of linking between a PHP file and a file html file

Tags: php, html

When I click a button to insert the data into the database by implementation of PHP code , but the problem is that it opens a new tab and shows PHP codes

html code

```
    <html>
        <body>
        <form action="InsertStudent.php" method="post">
        Student Id: <input type="text" name="SId" />
        Student Name:<input type="text" name="SName" />
        Marks: <input type="text" name="marks" />
        <input type="submit"  value= "Insert"/>
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

PHP code

```
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect:'.mysql_error());
      }
    mysql_select_db("my_db",$con);

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Student(StudId,StudName,Marks)
    VALUES ('9876543', 'Ahmed', '90')");

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Student(StudId,StudName,Marks)
    VALUES ('12344556', 'Mohammed', '95')");

    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page) ... and you **really** shouldn't be using the [mysql_*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) extension, it's been obsolete for years.

Answer (score -2):

every php script must be run on server. In your case you are not using server. You should install xamp or wamp server and then run your file on localhost.

step 1: download and install xamp from https://www.apachefriends.org/

step 2: copy or move your folder which contain the html and php file to c:\xamp\htdocs directory
step 3: after installation open the control panel and start apache server

step 4: open browser and type url localhost/your_folder_name

note: the folder name should not contain spaces or '-'. Name your html file as index.html

Comment: *step 3: open xampp-control.exe located in c:\xamp directory

Comment: OP mentioned neither windows , nor the fact that they did not have a proper stack already installed.

Comment: All steps worked but the same problem

Comment: I'm using wampserver software

Comment: the version of mysql 8.0.18
the version of PHP 7.3.12
the version of apache 2.4.41